# Facebook Wordpress Bad Feed Description

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I am having humbling issues with Facebook and Wordpress

**I am using**
WP ver 3.4.1
FB plugin Version 1.0.2

I Installed the plugin. Created a Facebook app.

What is happening is I am sharing the page on Facebook using Facebooks share button, send button, and subscribe button. Even if I copy and paste the post I get the following in the feed description.

> You may use these HTML tags and attributes: <​a href="" title=""> <​abbr title=""> <​acronym >title=""> <​b> <​blockquote cite=""> <​cite> <​code> <​del datetime=""> <​em> <​i> <​q cite=""> <​>strike> <​strong>

I think it is in a Facebook PHP file, but I looked there. I am kind of stumped to say he least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For some reason the Facebook for Wordpress plugin pulls in the comment instructions as the default description it uses in the og:meta tags, especially when there is no text associated with your posts or no excerpt set.

On my sites, I use the Facebook for Wordpress plugin for connectivity, but I've given up letting it generate my meta tags. I use [Wordpress SEO](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) instead, since you can specify what text should be in your description, titles, etc. There are other plugins that also do the same.

To inhibit the Facebook for Wordpress meta tags, add this to your theme's functions.php:

```
//Remove the Facebook for WP tags until they get their s**t together.
remove_action('wp_head', 'fb_add_og_protocol', 10);
```

Comment: Trying now.. Thanks. No luck yet with that. I have installed and configured Yoests' WP SEO plugin. That did not help at all. I am still messing with settings as we speak....I just cant help but think this is coming from Facebook, OpenGraph meta data.

Comment: Don't forget to run your pages through the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to reset the Facebook cache after you make any changes.

Comment: cpilko, site is http://psychotichumor.com, fan page is Psychotic Humor. All help is genuinely appreciated, this has troubled me for a few days now.

Comment: I ran my sites URL through the FB debugger. The errors are as follows                                                              Object Base Domain Not Allowed: Object at URL 'http://www.psychotichumor.com/' of type 'website' is invalid because the domain 'www.psychotichumor.com' is not allowed for the specified application id '462363170461252'. You can verify your configured 'App Domain' at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/462363170461252.

Comment: I think it is my OG setup. I have the app recreated. I started fresh, listed my site URL and domain (the same, right?), then I create the new app. I added that info in WP at the FB settings (token, namespace). What I am seeing at http://psychotichumor.com is a Subscribe button that still subscribes users to MY personal FB page, not our Fan Page I am trying to admin and add these features to. I am starting to look at wordpress#author-og-setup. Any thoughts?

Comment: You're still getting the FB og tags. Add the line of code from my original post to your theme's functions.php, and visit the debugger to refresh the FB cache. Yes, the subscribe button is buggy too. For whatever reason the plugin can't separate a personal page from a fan page.

Comment: You should post your issues at the official plugin support site: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/facebook

Comment: Great. So that explains why you were the only volunteer that could shed light on the issue, and why I have been stumped for three days! :)   I will add the snippet to my function.php now. Then will refresh FB cache. Very, VERY frustrating. We have 300,000 + fans and I REALLY would rather not make us all look stupid with a Subscribe button that points to my personal profile rather than the Fan Page's profile page.

Comment: You should also close your own duplicate posts here on SO before they ding your reputation too badly.

Comment: Closed dup. threads. Now I added remove_action('wp_head', 'fb_add_og_protocol', 10); at the end of my functions.php, and that did not do anything at all. I STILL have the annoying tags in the feed description.

Comment: The [Debugger is still throwing an error](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.psychotichumor.com%2F2012%2F09%2F04%2Fthis-is-it%2F).

Comment: I created a test site on another host. I simply installed the FB plugin, then created a post and believe it or not problem is GONE. I believe this shows the issue lays within my theme, as I did not install Custom Community theme on the test site. I have submitted a support request to the theme developer after some searching again there did not show anyhthing